# PHPUnit is running super slow

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Typically my test suite works well. But today, when I run phpunit, I got this.

[image: PHPUnit fails to run]

It takes minutes for one test case to run, while typically it takes like 10 seconds.

Comment: What if you try to run a specific test using `phpunit --filter=test_name`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducing test case that shows the problem you are reporting.

Without such a minimal, self-contained, reproducing test case I will not be able to investigate this issue.

Are you absolutely sure that you are not mixing different versions of PHPUnit?

Comment: This can have many reasons and in such a broad description this is hard to answer. Do the tests run at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use of SQLite database

   // Inside phpunit.xml

   Specify the env database connection and database name to

   ```
       <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
       <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
   ```
2. Filtering the tests:

> vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Test/Path/To/TestClassName;
>
> vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testNameOfTheFunction;

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with laravel phpunit. it was taking long time like 30Mins or more , solved this using below command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

so here need to remember whenever you will try to run phpunit script make sure to run above command of you

```
> vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Test
```